# need email address to get from google plus

Tags: email, google-plus

I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button#step_3_adding_a_sign-in_button_to_your_page) method to login with google plus, It's working properly, I need email of user in callback but this method in return did not give email address. what should I do for email, is their any other method which return email or we can get user email using access token?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional scope to the request. Email-providing scopes have recently changed, with older ones being deprecated. The full list is at https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes, but you can probably safely just use the *email* scope in addition to the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope. Scopes are specified by listing them with a space between each one, so your button configuration might look something like this:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email">
  </span>
</span>
```

You would use the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API to access the full profile of the user, which would include the [emails](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#emails) array. Each element of the array contains the type of the address (home, work, etc) and the address itself. The *email* scope just lists the address directly associated with the account, while other scopes provide other publicly available addresses, so they may not provide further information.

**Note that the older userinfo.* scopes are deprecated and may stop working in September 2014.** See https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable for details.

**Update**: To be clear - the sign-in button does *not* give you the email itself. It requests permission to get the email address and user profile information. What it gives you is an access token that you can use for further requests.

As both @DalmTo and I have pointed out, in order to actually get the information, you need to call the API endpoint of [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). Go to this page and go to the *Examples* section and select JavaScript from the pull down for an example. You will also need to load the javascript client library: see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples for some examples, but in particular you will need a line like

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoad"></script>
```

which loads the client library (and calls the onLoad() function when it has been loaded) and then something like

```
<script>
  function onLoad(){
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', onClientLoad);
  }
</script>
```

The onClientLoad() callback will be called when the client is loaded, and should set a marker to indicate things are set to make the call. Then, as part of the signinCallback() function, you would make sure this marker is set (indicating the client library is ready) and use the gapi.client.plus.people.get() method to make the request. Possibly something like this as part of the signed in block:

```
gapi.client.plus.people.get({
  'userId': 'me'
}).execute(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

This does a call to people.get, requesting the profile of a particular user. The special userid of "me" indicates it should be for the user that is signed in. Calling execute() with a callback function executes the request, returning a response object. In this example, we're just printing it, but it will be a JSON object containing the user's profile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do that data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email">  but it's not returning email. I need emailid of that person who is login in my web using google plus auth. please guide me what should I do?

Comment: Returning json is {"state":"","access_token":"***",
"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3600","code":"***",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "id_token":"*****",
 "authuser":"0","num_sessions":"1","session_state":"***",
 "prompt":"none","client_id":"*******",
 "g_user_cookie_policy":"single_host_origin","cookie_policy":"single_host_origin","response_type":"***",
 "issued_at":"140182","expires_at":"1014176","g-oauth-window":{},
"status":{"google_logged_in":true,"signed_in":true,"method":"PROMPT"}}

Comment: I've added an elaboration about what we mean by calling "people.get".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` it should let you request the email address then using `plus.people.get`

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback"
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
  </span>
</span>
```

you can test the API here:  [plus.people.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get)

Note: a user can have more then one email you probably want the one with type `account`

Comment: I used It, following error comes,
Error: invalid_request
request_visible_actions not allowed for scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Comment: when i removed comma , from the data-scope's both links it work properly but it doesn't give the email. what should I do for get email?  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">